# How to convert a conditional statement to a simple expression? Is compounding a return this way Acceptable practice?

Tags: python-3.x, return

The exercise I am doing was given by a book that takes a dictionary argument and asks for me to give a return value of True or False. I am new to Python 3 and as a personal exercise for learning I want to convert all the conditions of a "valid dictionary as a chessboard into" a single return value. I haven't actually tested this code for errors as it isn't finished, but I did run it through an online validator I found https://extendsclass.com/python-tester.html.

I want to know how I can convert the following 2 code blocks into simple expressions to be used in the return statement in my function below, You can see below that I've converted most expressions into the return value already with "and" because "ALL expressions must == True"

```
for pieces in dictionary.values():
    if all(pieces.startswith('b')) or \
         all(pieces.startswith('w')):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The above code block loops through the dictionary keys passed to function as "pieces",
and compares each key individually to determine if it starts with a value of 'b' or 'w'. So if any key does not start with 'b' or 'w' the dictionary "chessboard" is false as it contains an improper piece. Ok I think I see an error in this I'm going to look into it and try to figure it out. Ok I noticed some errors in the above code that need to be addressed I am currently researching how to properly execute the above code.

```
for square in dictionary:
    try:
        if int(square[:0]) <= 8 and \
            square[-1] <= 'h':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

I worked on the above code block a very long time and am still not sure that's the "best" implementation of what I want it to do. But I am still new and did my best.
Anyway it slices the dictionary key and compares the first char in the key to make sure it isn't over 8 which is the maximum "valid range" if over valid range it returns false and anything not int is obviously automatically False and returned as such by the "exception".

Then it slices the dictionary key to get the last char of the dictionary key and compares it to <= 'h' as that is the valid range and anything over 'h' or not a valid type value will return as False.
And then it compares the results of True/False "and" True/False with "and" because both conditions must be True.

Here is the function as it currently is with a test dictionary at the end:

```
def cBV(dic):                        # (c)hess(B)oard(V)alidator
    Err = 'Error: Invalid Board -'
    if not isinstance(dic, type({})):
        raise TypeError('Object passed to cBV is not of type <class dict>')
    
    chess_pieces = {'bk pieces': 0, 'wh pieces': 0,
                    'bk pawns': 0, 'wh pawns': 0}

    # converts dictionary values into keys and assigns those keys "counn of values"      
    for squares, pieces in dic.items:
        if pieces.startswith('b'):                 # alt if pieces[:0] == 'b':
            if pieces.startswith('bpawn'):         # alt if pieces == 'bpawn':
                chess_pieces['bk pawns'] += 1
            chess_pieces['bk pieces'] += 1
        elif pieces.startswith('w'):
            if pieces.startswith('wpawn'):
                chess_pieces['wh pawns'] += 1
            chess_pieces['wh pieces'] += 1
        
    return 'wking' in dic.values() and \                
            'bking' in dic.values() and \
            chess_pieces['bk pieces'] <= 16 and \
            chess_pieces['wh pieces'] <= 16 and \ 
            chess_pieces['bk pawns'] <= 8 and \
            chess_pieces['wh pawns'] <= 8 and \ 
            


dict = {'8h': 'wking', '2c': 'bking', '3a': 'wpawn', '3b': 'wpawn', '3c': 'wpawn',
    '3d': 'wpawn', '3e': 'wpawn', '3f': 'wpawn', '3g': 'wpawn', '3h': 'wpawn', '4b': 'wpawn'}
test = cBV(dict)
print('Is this a valid chessboard? ' + str(test))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have now is good, and you should feel proud - there are more fancy techniques for making things more concise, and you'll get more used to them as you wrap your head around how the various data structures work.

```
    for pieces in dictionary.values()
        if pieces.startswith('b') or \
             pieces.startswith('w'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

can be converted to the one-liner

```
return all(
    piece.startswith('b') or piece.startswith('w')
    for piece in dictionary.values()
)
```

which does a few things.

- The `all()` function takes any iterable object, and returns `True` if all of the values in that iterable are truthy. If even one of them is not, then it 'short-circuits' and returns `False` instead.
- As our argument to `all()`, we give a "comprehension". A comprehension is essentially a one-line `for` loop, of the form `f(element) for element in iterable`: it performs whatever `f(element)` is, for every `element` in the iterable.

  - In our case, the iterable is `dictionary.values()`, which returns all of the *values* (but not the keys) in `dictionary` (which, here, is `'wking', 'wpawn', ...`). In this case, these are strings.
  - `piece` is what we assign each element of, for each 'iteration' of the comprehension. It'll run for `piece = 'wking'`, then for `piece = 'wpawn'`, etc.
  - `piece.startswith('b') or piece.startswith('w')` is the function that we perform for each `piece`. This outputs either `True` or `False`, depending on whether the conditions are met.
  - You can wrap a comprehension in square-brackets `[]` to have it output as a regular list. However, if you give a comprehension as an argument to a function like `all()`, which is what we're doing here, then it will end up as a "generator", a slightly more efficient object that only calculates one object at a time. For our purposes, this isn't important.
  - The comprehension, overall, produces a series containing either `True` or `False`, that `all()` will consume.

---

Similarly with your second code snippet. You have the basics down, but can be more concise. Your code:

```
def allSquaresAreInRange(dictionary):
    for square in dictionary:
        try:
            if int(square[:0]) <= 8 and \
                pieces[-1] <= 'h':
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

can be turned into

```
def allSquaresAreInRange(dictionary):
    try:
        return all(
            (1 <= int(row) <= 8) and ('a' <= col <= 'h')
            for (row, col) in dictionary
        )
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Here we make use of a few things:

- As before, we use `all()`, and as before, we use a comprehension. But this time, we iterate through `dictionary` directly

  - Iterating through a `dict` is functionally identical to iterating through `dict.keys()`. So, we're iterating through the keys `'8h', '2c', ...`
- Each key is a two-character string. Strings are iterable, just like lists are, and most iterables have an interesting property called "multiple assignment": if we assign exactly as many variables as the iterable has elements, then those elements get split up.

  - `(row, col) = '8h'`, for example, is functionally identical to `row = '8h'[0]` and `col = '8h'[1]`. In both cases, we're left with `row = '8'` and `col = 'h'`.
  - This produces a `ValueError` if the number of elements on either side is mismatched - for example, if the key has only one character, or only three characters. A byproduct of this is that `row` and `col` are guaranteed to be exactly one-character long strings, if that error doesn't happen.
- Our condition checks if the `row` is between 1 and 8, and whether the `col` is between A and H, using greater than/less than signs. This returns `True` or `False`, once again.

  - As you seemed to discover, using `int()` on something that doesn't represent an integer will *also* throw a `ValueError`.
- This new snippet keeps the `try`/`except` blocks you came up with in yours, because they work just fine.

---

Python has a bit of a culture surrounding it that prides 'efficiently-written' code. Which is to say, code that looks as fancy as possible, and follows Functional Programming paradigms. Comprehensions, as well as `all()` and `any()`, are a big part of that, and so they're probably the 'correct' solution for any problem which they *are* a solution for (if they can be written concisely).

Similarly, the snippet

```
if condition:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can almost always be condensed to

```
return condition
```

(or `return bool(condition)`, in the case that `condition` deals with a value that has truthiness but isn't a boolean, such as `None` or an empty list or string). If this is applicable, it's good practice (but again, it's not always applicable).

The most important thing, though, is that your code works the way you want it to, and that it's clear enough for you to come back to it a few months down the line and figure out *what* you were doing, and *why* you were doing it that way. There are some cases where things *can* be written as comprehensions but that makes them extremely complicated and unreadable - and in those cases, it's sometimes a good idea to not write them as comprehensions, and do it the more verbose way. Just keep that in mind as you're continuing to develop, and you'll do fine.

Comment: Ty I learned a great deal. Just to clarify were you saying in the second part I can define the above function then use it in the "return" of my current function like so?

def cBV(dic):
    return  allSquaresAreInRange(dictionary)

Comment: You would want to define it as a second function, then call it in an `if` statement. Remember that `return` will jump _all the way out of your function_ regardless of whatever follows it, so if you need to do something complicated in, say, an `if` statement, you can build a smaller function, then call it to get its return value.